# Requesting images from Google Cloud makes page extremely slow

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am making a PHP Google App Engine site and I've found that requesting images from the Google Cloud service makes the page load extremely slow.

Without loading in the images it takes around 0.5s for the page to load and with the images it takes 10-15s. I assume I am doing something wrong so any help would be much appreciated.

[See this example](http://aupres-fabric.appspot.com/).

**My Code**

```
require_once "google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php";
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

...

function cloudStorageUrl($url, $size, $crop) {
    if (file_exists($url)) {
        $object_image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_image_file, ['size' => $size, 'crop' => $crop]);
        return $object_image_url;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it's google api slowness. Can you do it with JavaScript? It will help the page load time

Comment: The pages is mostly images so even if I did use JavaScript to load in the images later on the page still wouldn't be usable.

Comment: does google api tell you something about slowness?

Comment: There's no error messages in the console that I can see. I assume it's just something wrong with my implementation.

Comment: you know you can re-use the getImageServingURL once generated?

Comment: Oh ok maybe that's what I'm doing wrong. How would I save the URL though?

Comment: well, I save it in a model field relating to the object that has an image but...

Comment: You need to save the URL that's returned. If you don't want to put it in CloudSQL at least put it in memcache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Paul & Stuart I solved this issue by creating a table in Google Cloud SQL where I could store the url returned from Google Cloud Storage so that I didn't have to repeatedly request the url.

**Code Example**

```
// Cloud Storage URL function
function cloudStorageUrl($url, $size, $crop) {
    if (file_exists($url)) {
        $object_image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_image_file, ['size' => $size, 'crop' => $crop]);
        return $object_image_url;
    } else {
        return 'none';
    }
}

// Connect to database
$db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>;dbname=guestbook', 'root', '');

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `id`="'.$id.'"') as $row) {
    // Check if Cloud Storage URL already exists
    if ($row['url'] && $row['url'] !== 'none') {
        $url = $row['url'];
    } else {
        // Get the Cloud Storage URL and save it
        $url = cloudStorageUrl($row['cloud_storage_location'], 400, false);
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `images` (id, url) VALUES (:id, :url ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=VALUES(url))');
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => intval($id), ':url' => htmlspecialchars($url)));
    }
}
```